# Configure puppet to install particular Apache version from PPA

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, vagrant, apache2

My problem is similar to [Installing package from PPA using Puppet](https://serverfault.com/questions/526919/installing-package-from-ppa-using-puppet) but I don't know how to make it work.

I want Puphpet to apt to install Apache 2.4.23-5.0 this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) instead of the normal deb repo.  There is already a version of the same name in the deb repo so it's important that I get this custom version that contains a backport.

I'd like to use the [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/622553/50359) offered by @msanford, but don't know where to start.

Can I just append this fragment:

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:ondrej/apache2':}

package { 'apache2':
  ensure  => 'installed',
  require => Apt::Ppa['ppa:ondrej/apache2']
```

to the end of .../vm/profile/my-box/puphpet/puppet/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add `Package['apache2']` to your `apt` module, that doesn't make any sense. It should be in a `apache2` module.

Regardless, the package needs to require `Exec['apt_update']` to ensure that the apt-get update is completed before installing the package. You also should ensure the package uses the version you want.

```
apt::ppa { 'ppa:ondrej/apache2':}

package { 'apache2':
  ensure  => '2.4.23-5.0',
  require => [Exec['apt_update'], Apt::Ppa['ppa:ondrej/apache2']]
}
```

Here, I'm assuming that the version you listed is the same as the deb version. Sometimes the string is slightly different.